# ipcMain listener not registering correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, ipcrenderer, ipcmain

Am having some troubles with ipc messages between the main and renderer processes in an electron app.

The ipcRenderer is sending the message correctly (I can see it from devtron) but the ipcMain is not listening to anything

code in main.js

```
const {ipcMain} = require("electron");
...
let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
...
  ipcMain.on("mainWindow-minimize", (event, arg) 
  => {
    console.log("On minimize from main");
    mainWindow.minimize();
  });
...
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);
```

code in renderer.jsx

```
import React from "react"
impor {ipcRenderer} from "electron"
...
export default class App Extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.headerOnClick = this.headerOnClick.bind(this);
  }

  headerOnClick(message, event) {
    console.log("button clicked");
    ipcRenderer.send(message)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => this.headerOnClick("mainWindow-minimize", event)} />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you recollect ever finding a solution to this? I am having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call createWindow function in  main so the listener is created.

Comment: thanks for the reply. yes am calling createWindow, am just putting the relevant lines of the code.